Generate code coverage for a single test suite
I wish to determine which files are covered by each of my test suites separately. I am using PHPUnit 10.5 with Xdebug for code coverage on my PHP 8.1 project.
Here is what my phpunit.xml configuration file looks like:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="example">
            <file>./ExampleTest.php</file>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <source>
        <include>
            <directory suffix=".php">../src</directory>
        </include>
    </source>>
    <coverage>
        <report>
            <html outputDirectory="html-coverage"/>
        </report>
    </coverage>
</phpunit>

I have done some research but haven't found anything helpful. Is there a way to achieve this?
Could it be that seeking code coverage for a single test suite is considered bad practice, and that's why no one tried to do it?
Any advice or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

What about running just for a specific test suite?  phpunit --testsuite example
https://docs.phpunit.de/en/10.5/organizing-tests.html#organizing-tests-xml-configuration

I thought I tried running a specific test suite, but I hadn't. It could be a good way of doing it, as it generate a coverage report with 0% coverage for any files that are not covered by the test suite.
Your comment helped me find a workable solution to my problem. However, I believe there could be a better way to achieve this, but I haven't figured it out yet. If anyone has a more elegant solution, I'd love to hear it.

I found an interesting workaround to achieve this.
The XML coverage report includes a <coverage> element that lists the tests covering the class :
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<phpunit xmlns="https://schema.phpunit.de/coverage/1.0">
  <file name="Example.php" path="\path">
    <!--   ...   -->
    <coverage>
      <line nr="9">
        <covered by="someNamespace\ExampleTest::testSomething"/>
      </line>
    </coverage>
    <!--   ...   -->
  </file>
</phpunit>

My main goal is to identify which test suite covers which files. With this information, I should be able to make an algorithm that map the relationships between the  elements, the test classes, and the test suites.
This isn't the solution I was hoping for; I expected a simpler way to directly correlate test suites with their coverage.
If anyone has a more efficient and cleaner way to do it, please share your solution! :)
